# Change the value of a variable from within a if conditional in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a loop where a variable called `e` throws random numbers from a range of 0 to 5. I have another variable called `eValue` that is only initialized. I would like that when my variable `e` has a value of 0, my variable `eValue` is 1 and the value that has `i` is printed when this happens.

With this I hope that if the loop is repeated and `e` again it gets value of 0, it will not change the printed value of `i`.

```
var n = 1...25
for i in n {
    let e = Int.random(in: 0...5)
    var eValue : Int? 
    if e == 0 && eValue != 1 { 
        eValue = 1
        print(i)
    } else {
        print("Variable 'e' has no value of 0 and 'eValue' already has a value equal to 1.")
    }
}
```

My problem is that `eValue` does not acquire the value that I give it inside the if conditional.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that eValue isn't setting, it's because you're resetting eValue every time you run the loop.

You are hitting your if statement, but then immediately resetting the eValue unless it just happens to hit on the last loop.

The fix is to take the initialization of eValue out of the loop:

```
var n = 1...25
var eValue : Int?
for i in n {
    let e = Int.random(in: 0...5)
    if e == 0 && eValue != 1 {
        eValue = 1
        print(i)
    } else {
        print("Variable 'e' has no value of 0 and 'eValue' already has a value equal to 1.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, just one question: Can I continue to use the `for` loop if I want the loop to be interrupted when `e` is 0?

Comment: @SebastiánVarellaGmz If you use ``continue`` then it just skips the rest of the current loop and restarts the loop. If you are wanting to leave the loop then you need to use ``return`` or ``break``, depending on the circumstances.